# Errors with the Gazebo 11 conda forge implementation on windows

Tags: gazebo-plugin, gazebo-model, anaconda

Anytime I run the `gzclient.exe` using the conda implementation, I get several errors.

Invalid partition name `[...]` on several times, and mainly Service is not valid errors for almost all the services. That is the `[/physics]`, `[scene_info]`, `[/marker]`, `[/marker/list]`... And also
Topic `[/ground_plane/joint_cmd]` is not valid.

It also doesn't connect to the model database of gazebosim or fuel ignition.

Error:

```
(robosim) C:\Users\Kwesi Manu Eghan>gazebo --verbose
Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 11.14.0
Copyright (C) 2012 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 11.14.0
Copyright (C) 2012 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

[Msg] Waiting for master.
[Msg] Waiting for master.
[Msg] Connected to gazebo master @ http://127.0.0.1:11345
[Msg] Publicized address: 172.25.160.1
[Msg] Connected to gazebo master @ http://127.0.0.1:11345
[Msg] Publicized address: 172.25.160.1
Invalid partition name [Keghan-PC:Kwesi Manu Eghan]
Invalid partition name [Keghan-PC:Kwesi Manu Eghan]
Invalid partition name [Keghan-PC:Kwesi Manu Eghan]
Invalid partition name [Keghan-PC:Kwesi Manu Eghan]
Invalid partition name [Keghan-PC:Kwesi Manu Eghan]
Invalid partition name [Keghan-PC:Kwesi Manu Eghan]
Invalid partition name [Keghan-PC:Kwesi Manu Eghan]
Invalid partition name [Keghan-PC:Kwesi Manu Eghan]
[Msg] Loading world file [C:/computing/anaconda3/envs/robosim/Library/share/gazebo-11\worlds/empty.world]
Invalid partition name [Keghan-PC:Kwesi Manu Eghan]
Service [/physics/info/plugin] is not valid.
[Err] [D:\bld\gazebo_1707251199167\work\gazebo\physics\World.cc:308] Error advertising service [/physics/info/plugin]
Service [/scene_info] is not valid.
[Err] [D:\bld\gazebo_1707251199167\work\gazebo\physics\World.cc:316] Error advertising service [/scene_info]
Service [/shadow_caster_material_name] is not valid.
[Err] [D:\bld\gazebo_1707251199167\work\gazebo\physics\World.cc:324] Error advertising service [/shadow_caster_material_name]
Service [/shadow_caster_render_back_faces] is not valid.
[Err] [D:\bld\gazebo_1707251199167\work\gazebo\physics\World.cc:333] Error advertising service [/shadow_caster_render_back_faces]
Service [/shininess] is not valid.
[Err] [D:\bld\gazebo_1707251199167\work\gazebo\physics\World.cc:341] Error advertising service [/shininess]
Invalid partition name [Keghan-PC:Kwesi Manu Eghan]
Invalid partition name [Keghan-PC:Kwesi Manu Eghan]
Service [/spherical_coordinates_surface_type] is not valid.
[Err] [D:\bld\gazebo_1707251199167\work\gazebo\physics\World.cc:404] Error advertising service [/spherical_coordinates_surface_type]
Invalid partition name [Keghan-PC:Kwesi Manu Eghan]
Invalid partition name [Keghan-PC:Kwesi Manu Eghan]
Invalid partition name [Keghan-PC:Kwesi Manu Eghan]
Service [/introspection/pjakcx/filter_new] is not valid.
[Err] [D:\bld\gazebo_1707251199167\work\gazebo\util\IntrospectionManager.cc:51] Error advertising service [/introspection/pjakcx/filter_new]
Service [/introspection/pjakcx/filter_update] is not valid.
[Err] [D:\bld\gazebo_1707251199167\work\gazebo\util\IntrospectionManager.cc:59] Error advertising service [/introspection/pjakcx/filter_update]
Service [/introspection/pjakcx/filter_remove] is not valid.
[Err] [D:\bld\gazebo_1707251199167\work\gazebo\util\IntrospectionManager.cc:67] Error advertising service [/introspection/pjakcx/filter_remove]
Service [/introspection/pjakcx/items] is not valid.
[Err] [D:\bld\gazebo_1707251199167\work\gazebo\util\IntrospectionManager.cc:75] Error advertising service [/introspection/pjakcx/items]
Topic [/introspection/pjakcx/items_update] is not valid.
[Err] [D:\bld\gazebo_1707251199167\work\gazebo\util\IntrospectionManager.cc:85] Error advertising topic [/introspection/pjakcx/items_update]
Invalid partition name [Keghan-PC:Kwesi Manu Eghan]
Invalid partition name [Keghan-PC:Kwesi Manu Eghan]
[Err] [D:\bld\gazebo_1707251199167\work\gazebo\util\IntrospectionManager.cc:293] Failed to publish items on topic[/introspection/pjakcx/items_update]
Invalid partition name [Keghan-PC:Kwesi Manu Eghan]
Invalid partition name [Keghan-PC:Kwesi Manu Eghan]
Invalid partition name [Keghan-PC:Kwesi Manu Eghan]
Invalid partition name [Keghan-PC:Kwesi Manu Eghan]
Service [/shadow_caster_material_name] is not valid.
[Err] [D:\bld\gazebo_1707251199167\work\gazebo\rendering\Scene.cc:227] Service call[/shadow_caster_material_name] timed out
Invalid partition name [Keghan-PC:Kwesi Manu Eghan]
Service [/shadow_caster_render_back_faces] is not valid.
[Err] [D:\bld\gazebo_1707251199167\work\gazebo\rendering\Scene.cc:249] Service call[/shadow_caster_render_back_faces] timed out
Invalid partition name [Keghan-PC:Kwesi Manu Eghan]
[Wrn] [D:\bld\gazebo_1707251199167\work\gazebo\rendering\Scene.cc:463] Ignition transport [/scene_info] service call failed, falling back to gazebo transport [scene_info] request.
Service [/marker/list] is not valid.
[Err] [D:\bld\gazebo_1707251199167\work\gazebo\rendering\MarkerManager.cc:137] Unable to advertise to the /marker/list service.
Service [/marker] is not valid.
[Err] [D:\bld\gazebo_1707251199167\work\gazebo\rendering\MarkerManager.cc:144] Unable to advertise to the /marker service.
Invalid partition name [Keghan-PC:Kwesi Manu Eghan]
[Wrn] [D:\bld\gazebo_1707251199167\work\gazebo\gui\MainWindow.cc:373] Ignition transport [/scene_info] service call failed, falling back to gazebo transport [scene_info] request.
Invalid partition name [Keghan-PC:Kwesi Manu Eghan]
[Err] [D:\bld\gazebo_1707251199167\work\gazebo\rendering\Visual.cc:385] Service name [/shininess] not advertised, not attempting to load shininess for visual with name [ground_plane::link::visual].
Topic [/ground_plane/joint_cmd] is not valid.
[Err] [D:\bld\gazebo_1707251199167\work\gazebo\gui\JointControlWidget.cc:393] Error advertising topic [/ground_plane/joint_cmd]
[Wrn] [D:\bld\gazebo_1707251199167\work\gazebo\transport\Publisher.cc:135] Queue limit reached for topic /gazebo/default/user_camera/pose, deleting message. This warning is printed only once.
[Wrn] [D:\bld\gazebo_1707251199167\work\gazebo\common\ModelDatabase.cc:213] Unable to connect to model database using [http://models.gazebosim.org/drc_practice_hinged_door/model.config]. Only locally installed models will be available.
[Err] [D:\bld\gazebo_1707251199167\work\gazebo\common\ModelDatabase.cc:395] Unable to get model name[http://models.gazebosim.org/drc_practice_hinged_door]
[Wrn] [D:\bld\gazebo_1707251199167\work\gazebo\common\ModelDatabase.cc:213] Unable to connect to model database using [http://models.gazebosim.org/collapsed_police_station/model.config]. Only locally installed models will be available.
[Err] [D:\bld\gazebo_1707251199167\work\gazebo\common\ModelDatabase.cc:395] Unable to get model name[http://models.gazebosim.org/collapsed_police_station]
```